# Cannot connect Feiyu-tech G6 Max to Sony ZV-E10 via cable

Tags: sony

According to the website, this Gimbal supports 'Take photo, Start/Stop Recording Video, Switch Photo/Video Mode, Electronic Zoom' via cable. ([compatibility list](https://store.feiyu-tech.com/pages/g6-max-compatible-list))

The only cable supplied that fits into the camera is the USB-C connector, however when I connect it to the camera and switch the camera on it goes into 'USB Mode' and displays 'To start USB Streaming, unplug the USB cable. Execute USB streaming function before connecting USB cable'.

How do I get the camera to not go into USB mode for file transfer and rather the data connection to work with the gimbal?

Answer (score 1):

In the menu settings, enable PC Remote function.

https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/2070/v1/en/contents/TP0002392805.html